# C programming, Function Pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

Having some problems with my given code. Thou it works accordingly, im required to implement the "transverse" & "transverseR" functions.

Also i have trouble understanding what the given function pointers are for: 
Function pointers => void (*visit)(link)

```
void traverse (link ls, void (*visit)(link)) {
  if (ls == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  (*visit) (ls);
  traverse (ls->next, visit);
  return;
}

void traverseR (link ls, void (*visit)(link)) {
  if (ls == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  traverseR (ls->next, visit);
  (*visit)(ls);
  return;
}


void square (link l) {
  // link tmp = NULL;
  int container = l->item;
  container = SQUARE(container);

  l->item = container;

}

void squareAll (link ls){

  link curr = ls;  
  while (curr != NULL){
    square(curr);
    curr = curr->next;
  }

  ls = curr;
}
```

Comment: Whats your problem with the `traverse` and `traverseR` functions? They look fine to me. As for understanding what e.g. `void (*visit)(link)` means, see [this link](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: Fine apart from the bit where they blow the stack if the list is long (or loops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These function pointers allows you to perform some custom actions using a function of your own on each list item as a list is being traversed. For example, you might write a function that decreases each node's data:

```
void decrease_item(link node)
{
  --node->item;
}
```

The when you can call `traverse(list_head, decrease_item)` to decrease a value of every item in a list. You can create a function for printing each element's item and so on.

Btw, in your code above you can rewrite `squareAll` function in a more elegant manner:

```
void squareAll (link ls){
   traverse(ls, square);
}
```

Comment: wow, that is brillant on the traverse(ls, square);

great code, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`Also i have trouble understanding what the given function pointers are for: Function pointers => void (*visit)(link)`

Your function pointer can store the address of any function with the type:

```
void ()(link) // a function that takes an argument of type 'link' as first
              // parameter and returns void.
              // ex: void random_func(link param)
```

`visit` is simply the pointer name used in your program.
You can declare, assign and execute a function pointer as followed:

```
// protoype of an implemented function
int char_to_int(char c);
// your pointer declaration
int (*pointer_name)(char);
// assignment
pointer_name = &char_to_int;
// use of a function pointer
(*pointer_name)(some_character);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said, less obfuscated syntax will make the code easier to understand.

```
typedef void(*visit_t)(link);


void traverse (link ls, visit_t visit) {
  if (ls == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  visit (ls);
  traverse (ls->next, visit);
  return;
}

void traverseR (link ls, visit_t visit) {
  if (ls == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  traverseR (ls->next, visit);
  visit (ls);
  return;
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb: C programmers who don't use typedef when using function pointers are either bad programmers or masochists :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void (*visit)(link)
```

this is a function pointer which take a type link and returns a void.

for eg:

there is a function `void function1(Link a)`

the you can call the function traverse like below:

```
traverse (ls, &function1) ;
```